# Group by Category and find Percent Change for given frequency

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a dataset, df, that I wish to group by the category and find the percent change for a given frequency

```
  Cat  Value       Date  
  A    1           7/1/2020
  A    2           7/2/2020     
  B    20          7/1/2020
  B    40          7/3/2020
```

Desired Output

```
 Cat  Diff   pct_change      Date

 A    1      100             7/2/2020                  
 B    20     100             7/3/2020
```

This is what I am doing

```
df1=df.groupby(pd.Grouper(key='Cat', freq='1D')).sum()      #Group by the Cat

df1['PercentageDiff'] = df1['Value'].pct_change().mul(100)  #Find Pct_change
                   
df1['ValueDiff'] = df1['Value'].diff()                      #Find Value diff
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you want working per groups with [`DataFrame.groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) and last remove first values per groups filled by misisng values by [`DataFrame.dropna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html):

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])

df['Diff'] = df.groupby('Cat')['Value'].diff() 
df['pct_change'] = df.groupby('Cat')['Value'].pct_change().mul(100)

df = df.dropna(subset=['pct_change'])[['Cat','Diff','pct_change','Date']]
print (df)
  Cat  Diff  pct_change       Date
1   A   1.0       100.0 2020-07-02
3   B  20.0       100.0 2020-07-03
```

Comment: @Lynnette - Hmmm, I rename columns names and swap order in `df['Diff'] = df.groupby('Cat')['Value'].diff()`, `df['pct_change'] = df.groupby('Cat')['Value'].pct_change().mul(100)` and last add `[['Cat','Diff','pct_change','Date']]` for expected order of columns, do you think remove `[['Cat','Diff','pct_change','Date']]` ?

Comment: It works, my mistake. I want to ask, is there a way to include the frequency in this code?df1=df.groupby(pd.Grouper(key='Cat', freq='1D')).sum() ??

Comment: @Lynnette - Can you change data for frequency column? Not sure if understand.

Comment: Sure, I mean, lets say I want to see how the percent increase changes per week, or per month. Is there a way to add that frequency? freq = '1W' etc? Like time series - Or by using Grouper? pd.Grouper(key='Cat', freq='1D')).sum()

Comment: @Lynnette - I think understand, do you think `df1=df.groupby(['Cat', pd.Grouper(key='Date', freq='1M')])['Value'].sum().reset_index()` for values per months?

Comment: ok I think it is something like this- I will research and build off of this. Thank you so much

Answer (score 1):

This should help:

```
    def f(x):
        d = {}
        d['Diff'] = x.iloc[1, 'Value'] - x.iloc[0, 'Value']
        d['Perc_change'] = 100*(x.iloc[1, 'Value'] - x.iloc[0, 'Value'])/x.iloc[0,'Value']
        d['Date'] = max(x['Data'])
        return pd.Series(d, index=['Diff', 'Perc_change', 'Date'])
    
    df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df.Date)
    df = df.sort('Date')
    df.groupby(['Cat']).apply(f)
```

Comment: This solution assumes that each category will have only two rows of data to deduce a difference and perc-change for each category.